# pyspark flatmat error: TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, python-3.5, flatmap

This is the sample example code in my book:

```
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext

conf = SparkConf().setMaster("spark://chetan-ThinkPad- 
E470:7077").setAppName("FlatMap")
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)

numbersRDD = sc.parallelize([1, 2, 3, 4])
actionRDD = numbersRDD.flatMap(lambda x: x + x).collect()
for values in actionRDD:
    print(values)
```

I am getting this error:
    TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

```
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRDD.scala:193)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.<init>(PythonRDD.scala:234)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner.compute(PythonRDD.scala:152)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:63)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:282)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    ... 1 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `flatMap` on an `Int` object

`flatMap` can be used in *collection objects* such as `Arrays` or `list`.

You can use map function on the `rdd` type that you have `RDD[Integer]`

```
numbersRDD = sc.parallelize([1, 2, 3, 4])
actionRDD = numbersRDD.map(lambda x: x + x)

def printing(x):
    print x

actionRDD.foreach(printing)
```

which should print

```
2
4
6
8
```